# Add unique line item meta as order meta data in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

I have meta data that is stored below the order line items, many times the data is that same. I am trying to save the unique meta values as order meta data, separated by commas and I if possible to add a text "these are your numbers" before this data.

So far I tried the code below but nothing is happening.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_update_order', 'add_unique_order_nummers_to_order', 10, 2 );
function add_unique_order_nummers_to_order( $order_id, $order ) {
  
  $allenummers = array();
  $items = $order->get_items();
  
  foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
    $allenummers[] = $item->get_meta( '_org_ordernummer', true );
  }
  $ordernummers_array = array_unique($allenummers);
  $ordernummers_unique = implode(',', $ordernummers_array);
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_Unieke_nummers', $ordernummers_unique );
}
```

I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Use the following simplified code with a different hook, based on your comment, when order status is changed to "we-fact" custom order status:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_we-fact', 'add_unique_order_nummers_to_order', 20, 2 );
function add_unique_order_nummers_to_order( $order_id, $order ) {
    $allenummers = array(); // Initializing
    
    // Loop through order 
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        $allenummers[] = $item->get_meta( '_org_ordernummer' );
    }

    if ( ! empty($allenummers) ) {
        $order->update_meta_data('_Unieke_nummers', sprintf( __("These are your numbers: %s"), implode(', ', array_unique($allenummers) ) ) );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: It's adding the meta data to the order but I need the action to take place when an order is being updated or set to "we-fact" (custom order status). Because this specific item line meta data is only added later in the process and can change until that status. So I changed the hook to 'woocommerce_order_status_we-fact'. But when I am changing to that status it's giving a fatal error.